# Xamarin forms Scrolling not working with PullToRefreshLayout in table view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I'm using https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout to implement a table view in XAML. Here is the structure

```xml
 <views:BaseContentPage.Content>
        <controls:PullToRefreshLayout x:Name="PullToRefreshLayout" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="RefreshPatientDetailsPage" RefreshColor="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}">            
                <StackLayout>
                <ActivityIndicator Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicator}" IsVisible="False"></ActivityIndicator>
                <TableView x:Name="ClinicleTableView" HasUnevenRows="True">                    
                 ----------------------------------------
                 ----------------------------------------
                </TableView>
            </StackLayout>            
        </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
    </views:BaseContentPage.Content>
```

When i scroll the page down, the pull to refresh is working. but the page is not scrolling. I want to make the page scroll down and fire the pull to refresh after the scroll is finished. how to do that?

Comment: Does it help to set `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` and `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` both in the scrollview and in the stacklayout?

Comment: When i use a scroll view here, the bottom items are not shown in the view. I'll try it with the stacklayout. @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas

Comment: I thought you were already using a stacklayout inside a scrollview? I would definitely go for that, since that's how the samples do it.

Comment: In fact, they don't support stacklayouts, only listviews and scrollviews.

Comment: When I use stacklayout inside scroll view the bottom items are not shown.when i remove scrollview the page scrolls fine as it contains a table view. then the problem is the pull to refresh is fired when scrolling. I cant scroll.

Comment: you should put the scrollview first inside the control PullToRefreshLayout, and then the stack layout inside of it, like this:
PullToRefreshLayout>ScrollView>StackLayout

Comment: i just noticed the last comment you made before mine, the last items are not showing probably because of spacing or some padding happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re arranged my XAML code and it works as i expected

```xml
<views:BaseContentPage.Content>               
   <StackLayout>
      <ActivityIndicator Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicator}" IsVisible="False"></ActivityIndicator>
         <controls:PullToRefreshLayout x:Name="PullToRefreshLayout" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="RefreshPatientDetailsPage" RefreshColor="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}">    
              <TableView x:Name="ClinicleTableView" HasUnevenRows="True">                    
                 ----------------------------------------
                 ----------------------------------------
              </TableView>
         </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
    </StackLayout>                    
 </views:BaseContentPage.Content>
```